# why the logcat display system logs as well

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

i am using android studio. and i edited the logcat messages so that only logs fom the App to be displayed. but at run time i find that the logact displays my logs and system 
log as well as shown in the following example:

```
11-03 09:45:39.061  12724-12931/? W/CSPPCtrl﹕ >>[rfcConnect()]<<//my log
11-03 09:45:39.061  12724-12931/? I/CSPPCtrl﹕ ->[rfcConnect()]-> rfcSocket socket connecting..//my log
11-03 09:45:39.065  12724-12931/? W/BluetoothAdapter﹕ getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback//system log
11-03 09:45:39.068    1968-2103/? D/BTIF_SOCK﹕ service_uuid: 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb//system log
11-03 09:45:39.197    1968-2130/? W/bt-sdp﹕ process_service_search_attr_rsp//system log
11-03 09:45:39.229    1968-2130/? E/bt-btif﹕ DISCOVERY_COMP_EVT slot id:9, failed to find channle,//system log
```

and i edited the logcat filter as shown in the image below
[image]

please let me know why the logcat still showing the system logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it..to have you App listed in android monitor, the option in

```
Tools->Android->Enable ADB Integration
```

must be checked first

Answer (score 0):

Above your "logcat" tab there should be 2 lists. One of them will contain your phone and the other list running apps. Make sure your app is chosen there.

[image]

Comment: yes, i have the same one in red on th right "No debuggable application" and on the left my device is listed

Comment: When your app is running it should be available to choose in the second list.

Comment: do u mean the on in red on the right?if yes, no my app is not listed there..how can i solve it

Comment: Not sure. It has to be there if you can run it from Android Studio. Maybe restarting IDE will help? http://i.imgur.com/mMZmEja.png

Comment: but iin your image the app name is not showing it is the device name only

Comment: Check my comment above. It's there. "com.codersmill.stacktest"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Edit Configurations >> Run/Debug Configurations

On the RIGHT corner

If you're using [Intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76FJF.png) you'll see a **Logcat** tab

For [Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRqM6.png) user it's **Miscellaneous**

Uncheck following options: 
 
Show logcat automatically
Filter to only show output from this application
Clear log before launch

And you ready to go

Comment: u mean from edit menu??it does not has option configratio

Comment: Sorry, it's 'Miscellaneous'  Uncheck 'Show logcat automatically' and 'Clear log before launch'

Comment: would u please tell me where can i find miscellaneous

Comment: I've uploaded the screen captures ,check out the links above

Answer (score 0):

[image: all]

[image: right]

[image: right]

[image: error]

Make sure u have choice the filter.

right : 2,3;

error :  4;